# Babel/browserify throws "Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected token o"

Tags: reactjs, browserify, babeljs, babel-core

Weird error when attempting to use browserify and babel:

```
./node_modules/.bin/browserify app/index.js -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]
```

gives:

```
SyntaxError: /.../package.json: Error while parsing JSON - Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1 while parsing file: /.../index.js
    at Object.parse (native)
    at ConfigChainBuilder.addConfig (/.../dash/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:155:65)
    at ConfigChainBuilder.findConfigs (/.../dash/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:107:30)
    at buildConfigChain (/.../dash/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/build-config-chain.js:66:13)
    at OptionManager.init (/.../dash/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:369:58)
    at File.initOptions (/.../dash/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:223:65)
    at new File
```

I have the proper presets installed for es2015 and react, but I have no idea why it's throwing up this error. The weird thing is, this command is working on my production server...

Any ideas?

Comment: Browserify examines `package.json` files and that's where the error is coming from, so it has nothing to do with Babel and the presets. If your `package.json` is identical to that on the production server (on which the command works), I'd go with a complete re-install of `node_modules`, etc.

Comment: I had a stray package.json file in the parent directory. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the  package.json parsing error, Check whether there is an package.json file at my user directory, if exist, delete it.